# Show text letter by letter inside input

Tags: jquery, html, input

I am trying to show a message inside an input tag letter by letter, like actually being written and targeting the value will only show each letter at a time, not one after another: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/6unfwbc3/1/)

**HTML**

```
<input class="mailchimp" type="text" spellcheck="false" />
```

**Jquery**

```
var fillInput = function (target, message, index, interval) {    
  if (index < message.length) { 
    $(target).val(message[index++]); 
    setTimeout(function () { fillInput(target, message, index, interval); }, interval); 
  } 
}

$(function () { 

  fillInput(".mailchimp", "Subscribe", 0, 100); 

});
```

If you change the `$(target).val(message[index++]);` into `$(target).append(message[index++]);` and create a div with the class mailchimp it will show each letter one after another.

How can I go about this? Thanks.

Comment: What is your query. I still can't understand

Comment: @ankitAgarwal I just wanted to be able to show an entire word, letter by letter inside the input tag, which I couldn't cause I didn't also append the char with value of input. LTasty answered my question nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need append char with value of input
**JS**

```
var fillInput = function (target, message, index, interval) {    
  if (index < message.length) { 
    $(target).val($(target).val()+message[index++]); 
    setTimeout(function () { fillInput(target, message, index, interval); }, interval); 
  } 
}

$(function () { 

  fillInput(".mailchimp", "Subscribe", 0, 100); 

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u28ajyfz/

Comment: That was fast :) Thank you ! I will accept it as soon as I can :)

Comment: I wanted to ask you something, in the case of your answer, how can a place, say, an alert after the typing is done?